# Safely uninstall only one instance of QGIS in W10, leaving the other one fully operational

Tags: qgis-3, installation, osgeo4w, windows-10

I've got QGIS 3.16.11 and 3.28.6 installed on my job's W10 laptop and on a few PCs across the organization. About to install 3.28 on a few more with 3.16 already installed, too.

I'm not really using the 3.16 version anymore, since 3.28 runs everything smoothly so far (and I could just reinstall it if need be). So, I'd like to uninstall 3.16 and leave 3.28 as the only working version.

But I can't find a way to do it that makes me feel completely safe. By "safe" I mean it **should** completely uninstall 3.16 and all its components (GrassGIS 7.8.5, SagaGIS 2.3.2, QtDesigner with 3.26 widgets, etc); but **shouldn't** uninstall neither 3.28 nor any of the components 3.28 requires (GrassGIS 8.2.1, SagaGIS 7.8.2, QtDesigner with 3.28 widgets, etc).

None of them whatsoever appear in W10's "Programs and Features" window. So, no way to proceed there.

The generic QGIS Start menu shortcut opens 3.16 and I could try its right-click uninstall. ¿Would you consider that safe, as per aforementioned description? I'd still like to keep that shortcut but pointing to 3.28, since it's the one anchored to the taskbar, but of course I could just re-create one later again.

Same right-click-menu uninstalling could be done from the shortcuts under the OSGeo4W folder in the Start menu. But is that safe?

[image: Start menu OSGeo4w folder shortcuts. Right-click menu brings an uninstall option for these]

I installed both QGIS instances using the OSGeo4W Setup wizard. (Gotta love it, too. Kudos to the team for such an excellent tool!)

I still have both OSGeo4W Setup programs I used to install them. Should I uninstall 3.16 from there? Is this the right, safe, way? Come to think of it, looks like this is the way. Would the 3.16 OSGeo4W Setup program detect the dependencies 3.28 requires?

[image: OSGeo4W I used to install 3.16. Maybe uninstall with these settings?]

Or would that risk breaking the 3.28 instance? Would I need to reinstall 3.28 from the latter OSGeo4W afterwards? Would it be safer to just wipe them all and install 3.28 from scratch? That'd be almost unaffordably time-consuming.

Have you got any experience with this?

Comment: The OSGeo uninstall should do it right, or otherwise it has a bug. But uninstalling all versions and installing 3.28 again is not necessarily very slow because all the dependencies are already downloaded into the OSGeo4W cache on your computer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, @user30184! 

I take it, then, that the Setup program used to install that particular instance of QGIS is the one that should be used to uninstall it, right? 

Do I just mark "uninstall" in every option it offers? Or are there specific ones I should mark or avoid?